# How to import CSV/JSON file with tweet ids in Python3?

Tags: python-3.x

I would like to import a JSON or CSV file with all tweet ids in Jupiter Notebook using Python 3. 
I tried with

```
    import json

    with open('/path/namefile') as json_file:
        data = json.load(json_file)
        print(data)
```

but I got the following error: `JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)`. 
Unfortunately when I try to open the file JSON using text, my computer goes slow and it cannot open the file at the end, so I am not able to see which columns I need to consider. However, the columns should be the following:

```
coordinates,created_at,hashtags,media,urls,favorite_count,id,in_reply_to_screen_name,in_reply_to_status_id,in_reply_to_user_id,lang,place,possibly_sensitive,retweet_count,reweet_id,retweet_screen_name,source,text,tweet_url,user_created_at,user_screen_name,user_default_profile_image,user_description,user_favourites_count,user_followers_count,user_friends_count,user_listed_count,user_location,user_name,user_screen_name,user_statuses_count,user_time_zone,user_urls,user_verified
```

Could you please tell me what I am doing wrong and how I can import these ids?
Many thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without looking at the contents of that input file, one can only guess at what the problem might be.

Since the `json` library throws an error at the very beginning of the file (`line 1 column 1 (char 0)`), it's likely that it's not a JSON file (may be CSV).

If you're unable to open it as a text file in your system (how big is the file?), you can use Python to read the first few characters in the file to figure out the nature of data.

```
with open('/path/to/file', 'r') as f:
    print(f.read(size=100))
```

That'll print the first 100 characters of the file, which should give you an idea of how to proceed next based on the nature of data. If it's a CSV file, it'll have a bunch of commas in the printed output.